# Replace element in vector if element is x and previous element is na, in R

Tags: r

```
foo <- c("a","a",NA,"b","a","a","b","b")
```

How to replace "b" by whatever if previous element is NA ?

```
foo[foo=="b" & "previous-element"==NA] <- "whatever"
```

So expected output would be :

```
result <- c("a","a",NA,"whatever","a","a","b","b")
```

So only "b" (many in real datas) preceded by NA would be changed.

Thank's for helping !

Comment: I'm struggling with the "previous element" condition. I can't find ways to meet this condition.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A simple solution:

```
foo[-1][foo[-1] == "b" & is.na(head(foo, -1))] <- "whatever"
```

---

*Update:*

A solution with `rollapply` from the `zoo` package:

```
library(zoo)
foo[-1][rollapply(foo, 2, identical, c(NA, "b"))] <- "whatever"
```

Comment: Wow, simple and close to what I tried, but I don't quite understand the use of -1 here. foo[-1] removes the first element of the list, how does this work ? If I can ask...

Comment: @Chargaff You never need to replace the first element since it inherently has no previous element.

Comment: @Chargaff There is no point evaluating the first element of `foo` as it, by definition, doesn't have a preceding element. Hence `foo[-1]` is used throughout (the `head()` is truncating from the other end) instead of `foo`

Comment: @Chargaff I added another solution to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way

```
foo <- c("a","a",NA,"b","a","a","b","b")

nas <- which(is.na(foo))  ## which are NA
bs <- which(foo == "b")   ## which are "b"

## the match() finds the index in nas that matches the one in bs - 1
foo[bs[match(nas, bs - 1)]] <- "whatever"
foo
```

The result is

```
> foo
[1] "a"        "a"        NA         "whatever" "a"       
[6] "a"        "b"        "b"
```

Wrap this into a function for ease of use:

```
whatever <- function(x) {
  nas <- which(is.na(x))
  bs <- which(x == "b")
  x[bs[match(nas, bs - 1)]] <- "whatever"
  x
}
```

which gives

```
> foo <- c("a","a",NA,"b","a","a","b","b")
> whatever(foo)
[1] "a"        "a"        NA         "whatever" "a"       
[6] "a"        "b"        "b"
```

Answer (score 2):

A totally convoluted solution using `embed` just for fun:

```
foo[which(
          apply(
                embed(foo,2),
                1,
                function(x) x[1]=="b" & is.na(x[2])
               )
         ) + 1
    ] <- "whatever"

> foo
[1] "a" "a" NA "whatever" "a" "a" "b" "b"
```